# How to add Custom HTML in Lightning Component Dropdown Menu?

Tags: slds, locker-service, menu, lightning-buttonmenu

I'm trying to create a dropdown menu with specialized internal options.

SLDS Menu - https://lightningdesignsystem.com/components/menus/

Respective Lightning Component for this is - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:menuItem

But I'm having hard time making a customized version out of it. I could not continue using the HTML markup alone, as the biggest drawback of that is, I can't control how to close my dropdown menu if user clicks outside the dropmenu. Standard `lightning:menu` button handles it correctly.

**This is how I envision my dropmenu to look like and I also want this menu to close itself as soon as user clicks anywhere outside this menu.**

Any help much appreciated.

[image]